# Finding or creating related entities with Waterline ORM

Tags: sails.js, waterline

Say I have two models:
Country:

```
attributes: {
name: {
  type: 'string',
  required: true,
  unique: true
},
cities: {
  collection: 'city',
  via: 'country'
}
}
```

City:

```
attributes: {
    name: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true
    },
    country: {
      model: 'country'
    }
}
```

I want to find/create both objects and relate them. This is the code I have:

```
Country.findOrCreate({name: object.Country}).exec(function createFindCB(error, country){
          City.findOrCreate({name: object.City, country:country}).exec(function createFindCB(error, city){
            console.log(city);
            console.log(country);
          });
        });
```

But it's not working. If I call it 100 times with the same city & country I expect to have only 1 instance of the country and 1 instance of the city in the DB. While I do have one 1 instance of the country there are 100 instances of the city. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't `{name: object.City, country:country}` be `{name: object.City, country:country.id}` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct code should be:

```
Country.findOrCreate({name: object.Country}).exec(function createFindCB(error, country){
          City.findOrCreate({name: object.City, country:country.id}).exec(function createFindCB(error, city){
            console.log(city);
            console.log(country);
          });
        });
```